# How can I prevent images from being "draggable" in a Windows RT WebView

Tags: css, windows-8, webview, windows-8.1

I've got a WebView that contains a page with images. Some of those images are the pretty faces for buttons, so the user will be clicking on them. If, during a click, the user drags the cursor a little, it drags the image as if you're dragging and dropping it somewhere.

This isn't a very nice user experience. I'd like to make the buttons act more like regular buttons, where if you move the cursor while the mouse is down, nothing happens to the location of the button.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5f5e4/1/)

css:

```
.btn {
  background-image: url('imageUrl');
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
}
```